# From command line, how to know which Firefox version is installed in windows/linux?

Tags: firefox, command-line

I need to know which Firefox version is installed on my system from command line of Windows
or Linux.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options#-v_or_-version), it seems that the `-v` argument (and more) is broken on Windows. If you follow the bug link on the site, it seems there is a workaround. I quote the comment:

> Workaround (works with Firefox,
>   Thunderbird, and, I suppose, other
>   programs too):
>
> ```
> <program-name> -h | more
> ```
>
> The bug happens because, without
>   redirection, the program releases its
>   stdout before handling the -help
>   parameter. With redirection, stdout is
>   not released and you can see the
>   output.

So for example for Firefox:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox>firefox -v | more
Mozilla Firefox 3.6.13, Copyright (c) 1998 - 2010 mozilla.org
```

It works for me at least. Without `| more` I get nothing printed. On Linux it works with or without the piping.

Answer (score 17):

On linux (debian, lenny), you can use -v:

```
firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 3.0.19, Copyright (c) 1998 - 2010 mozilla.org
```

(that was on a random server just now)

Answer (score 4):

On my *Windows 8* box I was aware that *Firefox Quantum* was installed and the `firefox` binary is placed within:

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox
```

So when I changed the directory to `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox` and issued the command **`firefox -v`** nothing was shown:

[image: firefox-v]

But when I issued the command **`firefox -v|more`** it worked perfecto:

[image: firefox-v_more]

Comment: Thank you! With the |more pipe to force the console pipe detection -v works just fine (Wndows10) 
`Mozilla Firefox 81.0.2`

Answer (score 2):

In 2018, FF 60:

```
firefox --version
```

output:

```
Mozilla Firefox 60.0.1
```

Comment: In 2020, FF 74, Windows 10:
`firefox -v | more`
or `--version` (instead of `-v`) was the only way to make Firefox print version info

Answer (score 1):

7 years later...

On newer version (I tried on 51.0.1) @Nömmik's answer doesn't work on Windows.

But you can try this workaround:

`firefox -v | find "Mozilla"`

Comment: Pretty embarrassing for a project of Firefox scale

Comment: Nömmik's answer seems to work on Windows as of Firefox 67.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work , try using ./firefox -v

Answer (score 0):

In RH7 try
"Firefox -v"
this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mozilla for keeping us on our toes... in a pandemic world that's what we would need... Anyway.. 2021 only works in
Windows 10 with the pipe:

c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox -v | more