# Get firefox version with python

Tags: python, firefox

I would like to know how to get the installed firefox-version on a linux system
and print a message if the installed version is older than 3.6.

My current solution is:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import re

cmd = 'firefox --version'
p = Popen(['firefox','--version'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

main_version_start = re.search("\d", stdout)

main_version_end = stdout.index(".",main_version_start.start()) 

main_version = stdout[main_version_start.start():main_version_end]

print main_version
```

With this approach I get the first digit. Same could be done for the number after the point.
Now I could make something like:

```
if main_version < 4:
    if sub_version < 6:
       print "Firefox version is too old"
```

Is there a better way of getting the installed version?

Comment: There is the `webbrowser` module, but I am not aware of any versioning support in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to get the nested comparison right is tricky… and unnecessary. Just do this:

```
if (main_version, sub_version) < (3, 6):
    print "Firefox version is too old"
```

Also, you're getting the versions as strings. You almost certainly want to convert them to integers. While it's true (in 2.x) that `'2' < 3`, it's also true that `'4' < 3`. (And, while you could fix that particular problem by comparing to `'3'` instead of `3`, it's also true that `'11' < '3'`.)

Meanwhile, when using regexps, it's generally much simpler to use capture groups than to use start and end values, as jedwards explains.

And of course you probably want some error handling. On a system without Firefox at all, your `Popen` call will raise an `OSError`.

As a side note, the standard terminology for the first two version components is `major` and `minor`, not `main` and `sub`.

Anyway, putting it all together (with shantanoo's simpler `subprocess` call):

```
def firefox_36_or_later():
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(['firefox', '--version'])
    except Exception as e:
        print "Failed to run Firefox: {}".format(e)
        return False
    try:
        major, minor = map(int, re.search(r"(\d+).(\d+)", output).groups())
    except Exception as e:
        print "Failed to parse '{}' for version number: {}".format(output, e)
        return False
    if (major, minor) < (3, 6):
        print "Firefox version is too old"
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a better way to get the version, but a better method of parsing the output might be, instead of:

```
main_version_start = re.search("\d", stdout)

main_version_end = stdout.index(".",main_version_start.start()) 

main_version = stdout[main_version_start.start():main_version_end]
```

Something like

```
(v1,v2,v3) = re.search("(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)", stdout).group(1,2,3)
```

On my headless system I get "Mozilla Firefox 15.0.1" which is parsed as

```
# v1: 15
# v2: 0
# v3: 1
```

Comment: Another method might be: version = tuple([int(x) for x in stdout.strip().split('.')])

Comment: @JimDennis: That will raise an exception, because `stdout` will generally be something like "Mozilla Firefox 3.6.18", or "Mozilla Firefox 3.6.18, Copyright (c) 1998 - 2010 mozilla.org"; either way, you'll be trying to do `int("Mozilla Firefox 3")`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using popen and PIPE, you may use check_output.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.check_output(['firefox', '--version'])
```

Parsing Mac output:

```
>>> tuple(map(int, output.split()[-1].split(b'.'))) > (4, 6)
True
```

For linux

```
>>> tuple(map(int, output.split()[2][:-1].split(b'.')))[:-1] > (4, 6)
```

Comment: The `subprocess.check_output` is a nice improvement, but the split logic is wrong. Given `"Mozilla Firefox 3.6.13, Copyright (c) 1998 - 2010 mozilla.org"`, `split()[-1]` will return `"mozilla.org"`, `split('.')` will return `"mozilla", "org"`, and mapping `int` to that will raise an `ValueError`.

Comment: I don't think the issue is Mac vs. Linux, but 3.6.x vs. something newer. (I believe the change was either between 1.9.2/3.6 and 2.0/5.0, or between 2.0/5.0 and 6.0.)

Comment: And even after that fix… 1.9.0 gives a _different_ format than 1.9.2/3.6. Which shows that this approach is too fragile, unless you're going to test every possible version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

With this, version 3.9 will pass "sub_version < 6". You should check if version is greater than :)

To get installed version, I don't see any better way ... Maybe check [From command line, how to know which Firefox version is installed in windows/linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644470/from-command-line-how-to-know-which-firefox-version-is-installed-in-windows-lin)

Comment: That link doesn't tell him anything more than he already knows. It suggests using `-v` rather than `--version`, but that's definitely not an improvement. It also shows a workaround for Windows, but he only cares about linux.