# Determine the firefox version available for update using Python

Tags: linux, firefox, python-3.x

I am looking for snippet which will check which version is available to download for updates. 
I use python 3.x. So it would be nice if anyone has a hint how i can check the version available on the server. The OUtput should generate a variable in which the version number of firefox is stored. for example 22.0

I am using linux as the operating system of my choice.

to be clear:
I don't want to know whhich version is already installed on my system. i want to know which version can be updated.

So far i got the following code:

```
def firefox_version_remote():
firefox_version_fresh = os.popen("curl -s -l  ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-i686/de/").read()
# short name for firefox version num fresh
fvnf = " "

for i in firefox_version_fresh:
    if i.isalpha() != True:
        fvnf = fvnf + i

return fvnf.strip()
```

this returns -22.0..2 where it should return 22.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644470/from-command-line-how-to-know-which-firefox-version-is-installed-in-windows-lin

Comment: nope i already know to determine the verision currently installed. this is not my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a regular expression to match the numbers you're trying to extract. That would be a lot easier. Something like this:

```
matches = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)+', firefox_version_fresh)
if matches:
  fvnf = matches[0]
```

That's assuming the version is of the form x.y potentially followed by more sub versions (e.g. x.y.z).

- `\d+` is one or more digits
- `(?:    )+` is one or more of everything in the parentheses. The `?:` tells the compiler that it's a non-capturing group - i.e. you're not interesting in extracting the data inside the parentheses as a separate group.
- `\.\d+` matches a dot followed by one or more digits

So the whole expression can be described as one or more digits followed by one or more occurences of a dot and one or more digits.

Comment: could you please explain to me how the regex in this particular case is working?

Comment: @l1zard Updated the answer with an explanation of the regex. Also noticed that I forgot to escape the dot in the regex so I fixed that too.